# Trouble in moving an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I want to move the image based on the coordinates from database.

I can already move the image (thing). But for example, i have x-coordinate as 293 and y-coordinate as 715, the image ends up moving to 293 and 715 BUT the image (thing) i'm moving is an arrow like 
[this](http://data:image/png;base64,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)

So i have to move the image but the upper left part of the image should be the one to locate the coordinates not the center part of it. Anyone who can help me with my problem? any help will be appreciated

here's my script so far,

```
<script>
function getClickPosition($valuex,$valuey) {
var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
var x1 = document.getElementById('valuex').value;
var y1 = document.getElementById('valuey').value;
var parentPosition = getPosition(x1.currentTarget);
var parentPosition = getPosition(y1.currentTarget);
var xPosition = x1 - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
var yPosition = y1- parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);

theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";

function getPosition(element) {
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 0;

while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}
return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position is relative to the top left corner by default. You have to manually offset it to get anything else. That's what the `theThing.clientWidth /2` and `theThing.clientHeight / 2` is doing in your code: moving the position up and left by half of the height/width. If you want to just use the top left position, replace this:

```
var xPosition = x1 - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
var yPosition = y1 - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);
```

With this:

```
var xPosition = x1 - parentPosition.x;
var yPosition = y1 - parentPosition.y;
```

Comment: it's noww working based on what i want. thank you so much ^^